# SocketAsyncEventArgs use a long sized buffer?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How do I use a long-sized buffer with SAEA's?  Buffer size and offset is only int,  what if my buffer is 10b bytes.  Is there a way to modify the microsoft code now that its opensource and rebuild it?
from System.Net.Sockets:

```
    // Buffer property.
    public byte[] Buffer {
        get { return m_Buffer; }
    }

    // Offset property.
    public int Offset {
        get { return m_Offset; }
    }

    // Count property.
    public int Count {
        get { return m_Count; }
    }
```

Comment: I doubt that would be a rewarding exercise. Why can't you just write it out/receive it a page at a time - for some arbitrary page size <= int range - and then copy?

Comment: Looks like I would have to do that.  Max array size for C# is int32.Max.  But why not a page at a time is because a large array would be stored on the LOH and prevent mem fragmentation